# Docker Permission Denied run docker as nginx

Tags: php, nginx, docker

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$code = addslashes($_GET['code']);
echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/docker exec d6ebc1b02e76 perl -e \"$code\" 2>&1");
```

When executing this PHP script from nginx I get the following:

```
time="2015-07-30T23:46:03-04:00" level=fatal 
msg="Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/d6ebc1b02e76/exec: dial 
unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a 
TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?"
```

Outside of giving nginx sudo access to docker is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract from the doc at

https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#optional-configurations-for-docker-on-ubuntu

"To avoid having to use sudo when you use the docker command, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the docker daemon starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group."

You may try that

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run docker commands as a non-root user: try like this
a. Create a user 'docker' - > #adduser docker, passwd docker
b. Add a group docker -> groupadd docker
c. sudo usermod -aG docker docker

Note Add entry to /etc/sudoers
%sudo All=(ALL:ALL)  ALL | %sudo All=(ALL:ALL)  ALL